# How to connect to RESTful web service with a client certificate from CentOS machine(not web server)

Tags: ruby, linux, ssl

I'm writing a small ruby code, trying to connect to a RESTful web service with provided client certificate(pkcs12) from my CentOS machine.

I can use httpie to successfully connect to the web server with the certificate from windows machine.  But somehow I can't make it happen on Linux machine.

## I tried to put extracted cert.pem to /etc/pki/tls/certs and private key to /etc/pki/tls/private.  Or I tried to create new cert store within the code, which doesn't work either, always got the following errors:

/usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:918:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

=====ruby code======

## !/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'openssl'

begin
    uri = URI.parse('https://api.test.com/rest/api/exports')
    args = {:"Client ID"=>'111111', :"Client secret"=>'11111'}
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(args)
    httpHM  = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
    httpHM.use_ssl = true
    httpHM.ssl_version="SSLv3"
    #cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
    #cert_store.add_file 'cert.pem'
    #httpHM.cert_store=cert_store

```
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

#response = httpHM.request(request)
httpHM.start do |http|
    response=http.request(request)
end
puts response.body
```

## end

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I also tried to make it happen on windows in Java, got the same error message while httpie works.  The question is still where I should put these client certs to and the application can read correctly from.  Thanks.